# How can I disconnect my Github account from AWS Code Pipeline?

Tags: github, aws-codepipeline

Whenever I try connecting to Github I get connected to the same account, I want to remove that connection and connect to a new GitHub account. If anyone has resolved this please help.
I tried:
I had a look at the settings but it does not provide any option to disconnect from Github

Answer (score 0):

If you log into a different GitHub account, then edit the GitHub action in your pipeline, it should show you a "Connect" button. If you click this, do the OAuth handshake again, and save your pipeline, it should now be connected to the new GitHub account.